# Chart.js 3+, Firefox 68 and Angular: "ReferenceError: "ResizeObserver is not defined"

Tags: angular, chart.js, polyfills

I have an Angular application using `Chart.js` 3+ and it needs to run in Firefox 68.

`Chart.js` 3+ uses `ResizeObserver` in its code, which is not supported by that specific Firefox version.

So, when I try to load my chart in Firefox, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: "ResizeObserver is not defined"

In other browsers or newer versions of Firefox it works properly.

After some research, I read that I could install a polyfill for `ResizeObserver` and many suggested the following: https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer

So I installed it in my project by typing `npm i @juggle/resize-observer` and then added it to the `polyfill.ts` file:

```
import '@juggle/resize-observer';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

But the error persists. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at how others fixed it, it seems like you still need to register it to the browser before you do anything with chart.js so it can use it:

```js
import {ResizeObserver as ResizeObserverPolyfill} from '@juggle/resize-observer';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.ResizeObserver = window.ResizeObserver || ResizeObserverPolyfill;
}
```

Comming from: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/plugin-site/pull/714

Comment: I also had this issue with a React.js app on iOS and this has saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Support for older browsers got dropped a while back, so you need a polyfill to keep chartJS working. if you have really old browser and you can't import, you can add a script from [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/). It's pretty heavy, but it will be an easy fix and you can add other polyfills easily if you need.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=ResizeObserver"></script>
```